# Apportable GCM implementation

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, apportable

Looking for further information how to implement registration and unregistration methods for Android Google Cloud Messaging.

Any piece of code or even how to use the BridgeKit wrapper of Apportable to do this will be appreciated.

I don't have too much skill in Java.

Answer (score 0):

See this [Apportable docs page](http://docs.apportable.com/publishing.html#google-play-gcm-setup) for a tutorial and this [github project for an example](https://github.com/apportable/Spin/tree/gcm_example).